# Trying to Display a web image correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

This is screen shot of my web page, under Offer image, there's image displaying a web image.

http://imageshack.us/a/img684/9584/screenshot20120920at335.png

However, the actual web image is

http://imageshack.us/a/img717/5240/1348180361.png

The code for that container is

```
   $('#image_upload_form input').change(function() {

            success: function ( data ) { 
                 var jsonData=data;
                if(jsonData.status==1)
                 {
                 var imagePath="http://www.test.com/play2win_offerimages/" + jsonData.image_name;

                    $('#offer_detail input[name=image]').val(imagePath);
                    myImage = new Image();
                    myImage.src = imagePath;
                                            myImage.width=100;
                                            myImage.height=100;
                    $(myImage).load(function() {
                        $('#offer_image').updateimgto(myImage.src);
                        });

                }  //status=1


            }   //success


        });      //submit
```

I set the image, myImage to 100x100.    Yet as you can see from the webpage only a portion of the image is shown.

Right now, my web image shown on page is cropped.. How to fix that?

I do not want crop, only to rescale to fit in the container.

html for image_upload_form

```
        <form id="image_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.test.com/play2win_api/offers/upload_image" method="POST">

   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="8192000" /> 

  <input name="offer_image" type="file" id="imagefile"/></form>
```

Comment: so you question is, you do not need the image to be cropped. you want it to be resized is that correct?

Comment: That portion of code is from the generated html code.

Comment: @shnisaka yes, that's correct.

Comment: @jason white: what html code is generated for `<img>` tag as a result? Why didn't you check that right after you've found it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @zerkms  it's form which use the post operation to post image and then get it back from server.  See above.

Comment: @jason white: I still don't see `<img>` tag in the html. Images are shown by `<img>` tag.

Comment: It's a dive not <img>   <div id="offer_image" class="img_preview_container" />
<a class="preview_overlay"></a>

Comment: OK, I see the <img> tag, it's dynamically added in . simple one <img src="http://..... alt="uploaded image>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing those two lines

```
myImage.width=100;
myImage.height=100;
```

Instead try to style the input inside the `#image_upload_form` and add the following code to your style:

```
width:100px;height:100px;
```

Comment: yes, I have that but it didn't work so I set it to the myImage also.

Comment: use @Nelson answer with my answer and you should have the perfect solution :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the height of the image, remove, or comment out your following line:

```
myImage.height=100;
```

just specifying the width the browser will re-scale the image according to that width.